# Does eating certain foods make me bigger?

Tags: the-sims-4

I noticed that over time, my sim has gotten really, really fat. So, I got him on a treadmill and eventually slimmed him down (previously, I had no fitness level at all). But it led me to wonder if my sim's eating habits had anything to do with it? Generally, I just make him eat pancakes all the time with the occasional side of cereal.

So my question is, does my sim's eating habits affect how big he is getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each food has a calorie value.

Calorie intake occurs on each bite.  If you are full and concerned about weight, don't finish the plate.

If a food isn't satisfying (such as cake), you'll tend to eat a second serving.  A second set of bites = more calories.

Most foods are 300 calories.

On the high side: a serving of lobster thermador has 800; a serving of cake has 500; a serving of omelet has 400.

On the low side: a serving of garden salad has 50; a serving of scrambled egg has 155; a serving of French toast has 200.

Pancake: 200.  Cereal: 120.

Keeping calorie intake lowish is only part of the battle.  You can get fat on garden salads if you spend all day sitting and not moving.  Jogging, treadmill or swimming are the best calorie burning activities.  Dancing has no effect.

Comment: Other weight management items: potions can be bought using whim points.  Serums can be researched by the Science career in GetToWork expansion pack.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Did you find the calories somewhere or are you just taking a guess?

Comment: It is easy to find such lists.  Here's one now:: http://www.carls-sims-4-guide.com/forum/index.php?topic=22051.msg392533#msg392533

Answer (score -1):

Yes, eating unhealthy food changes your body shape to round(er), just like real life. Sporting can help slimming down, but also eating healthy, such as salads, can help improve your figure.

From the [wiki](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Food):

> changing a Sim's fitness and body shape

Comment: That link isn't to Sims 4 content.